# Displaying error for specific file in codeigniter upload

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, extract-error-message

I have ha form, the form have more than one file uploading field like upload logo, upload background. While I am uploading the files using Codeigniter I can display uploading errors using using $this->upload->display_errors() call. But in my form I have two files to upload. I want to make error message more specific. Like:

=====Logo error====
Codeigniter uploading error message for logo

=====Background error====
Codeigniter uploading error message for background

As both of the files are uploading in the same form the display_errors() method return all the file uploaded error messages as combined. I tried to keep the errors at variable when logo upload error occurred. Then add just only the background error messages with that variable. But when adding the background error calling the method display_errors(), it return not only the background error but also the logo uploading error. It may be possible by clearing the display_errors() methods return value after the logo errors. But is it possible with codeigniter? Or how to get my desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter file upload? please show us some code would be help full.

Comment: Have you checked this link out? 
https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: User guide is now at http://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: hmm, the link that I mentioned still works. You can get help to upload file from that link undoubtedly :)